# UITextField with numbers and default keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-softkeyboard

Created a UITextField for "Postal Code/ZIP" field with a keyboardType of UIKeyboardTypeDefault. I would like to use the default keyboard but want the numbers & symbols to be shown by default as apposed to letters.

Apple does this when you are entering addresses in the Contacts.app.

Anyone know how to get this accomplished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` keyboard type.

Comment: Perfect thanks... i'm slowly learning how to use the Apple Developer docs. :)

Answer (score 6):

And a code example of what executor21 said:

```
UITextField* txt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```